# How to add more space to save items in list view threshold?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-view, list-view-threshold

I got warning 4780 items in my list, the limit is 5000. How can I add more space for the list?

Could someone help me please?

I am using SharePoint Online.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SharePoint 2016, you can change it in the Central Administration.

GO Central Administration --> Application Management --> Manage Web Application --> Select your web application, go to ribbon and click on the down arrow in the General settings to go into Resource Throttling. Then you can change the list view threshold.

[image]

**Update**:

If you are using SharePoint Online, you are not able to change the list view threshold. The only option available for you is to add index for the list or
add new views with filters to show less items.

Reference links:

1. ["The number of items in this list exceeds the list view threshold" when you view lists in Office 365](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/support/Lists-and-libraries/items-exceeds-list-view-threshold).
2. [Manage large lists and libraries in SharePoint](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/manage-large-lists-and-libraries-in-sharepoint-b8588dae-9387-48c2-9248-c24122f07c59?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US#ID0EAABAAA=Online).

Comment: Hi Jerry, question seems to be about SharePoint Online

Comment: @PS I will add explanations about SharePoint Online. Normally i always assume it to be SP2016 when seeing something like SharePoint 2016 online. Thanks for your notification.

Comment: Tks Jerry, I will wait for the Online ^^

Comment: Hi Vinh, unfortunately there is no option in SP Online to increase this threshold. It's better to delete unnecessary items, or move them to a different list, or even - not use SharePoint list for this kind of data. Also this limit does not mean that your data will not be accessible - you should be only worried if you are doing filtering, sorting, grouping on the list once it reaches 5000 items.